# Collect external script output in a variable in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am new to bash scripting but after trying several syntax approaches and researching, I am a bit stuck storing the result of an external script call in my bash script. $r has no visible value when I echo it...

From the command line, it works as expected:

```
 ./external-prog 23334
 echo $?
 2
```

```
#!/bin/bash

# build the command
c="./external-prog 23334"

# invoke command that returns an integer value
eval "$c"

#collect result in $r
r=$(eval "$?")

#see result
echo $r
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just want to run the command and retrieve it's returned value, so there is no need far `eval`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# run the command
./external-prog 23334

#collect result in $r
r=$?

#see result
echo $r
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below, storing the external script result in a variable :

```
c=$(./external-prog 23334)   
echo $c
```

Answer (score 0):

This sequence `$?`will return the error code of the last process not the output.
Check this out

```
$ echo ok; echo $?
ok
0
```

First echo printed 'ok' and the second one printed 0, which means command succeeded. And a non 0 code means some kind of error occured.

So this

```
 ./external-prog 23334
 echo $?
 2
```

Means that `external-prog` failed and the error code is 2 whatever it means.
And to catch the output of some command to a var you need this

```
var=$(echo ok)
$ echo $var
ok
```